# Declare all columns in a database to be NOT NULL by default?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

Rather than littering my schema with NOT NULL almost everywhere I'd rather declare somewhere that all columns should be NOT NULL unless explicitly 'CAN BE NULL' or something.

Is there some way to do this?  I'm using SQLite but curious for PostgreSQL also

Comment: No, by default a column can be null. afaik no database allows the default to be *not null*.

Comment: If your schema is so large you want this 1) consider whether the schema could be smaller and 2) consider using a schema builder rather than raw SQL.

Comment: I would guess that the SQL Standard ([ISO/IEC 9075-1:2016](https://www.iso.org/standard/63555.html)) requires columns to be nullable by default, but I do not want to pay 178 Swiss Franc to read the spec :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set all table columns to NOT NULL at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134892/how-to-set-all-table-columns-to-not-null-at-once)

Comment: I don't think dynamic SQL to automtically amend each column definition is what the OP had in mind - besides that answer doesn't take into account that the script will fail if any rows exist containing NULL.

Comment: SQLite docs for the schema table explicitly say modifying it can cause database corruption, so it sounds like the approach described in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916266/declare-all-columns-in-a-database-to-be-not-null-by-default would be painful at best for SQLite (would need to produce ALTER TABLE statements from the schema somehow).

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no databases that I know of that allow this. It would certainly be non-standard if they did.

Answer (score 1):

One of the dumbest things I ever saw in Microsoft SQL Server (yes, I know) were the two commands:

- [SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-null-dflt-on-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-null-dflt-off-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Not one, no, two separate commands. They read in part "Modifies the behavior of the session to override default nullability of new columns when the ANSI null default option for the database is false."

After finding these, I figured I could never assume anything about how SQL handled column default NULLability, and now I *always* set NULL/NOT NULL myself, no matter what RDBMS I use. (Back then I assumed this was an ANSII standard, and now I'm scarred for life.)